# failed attempt to create a min(a,b) function in freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I need a way to find the minimum of two values in FreeMarker, and I tried doing this, but it fails:

```
<#function min a b>
  <if a gt b>
    <#return b />
  <else>
    <#return a />
  </if>
</#function>

   ...

/* min#1 ${min(0.280617, 1.0)} */
/* min#2 ${min(1.0, 0.280617)} */
```

Instead of printing out 0.280617 on both lines, I get this:

```
/* min#1 1 */
/* min#2 0.280617 */
```

Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<if ...>` is just static text (as it doesn't start with `<#` or any other reserved pattern), and functions ignore static text (they don't output anything), so your function has just returned at the first `#return`, which was run unconditionally since, again, `<if ...>` is just static text. (Non-whitespace static text should be an error, but that would be very backward-incompatible to fix now, after 10+ years... Maybe in 2.4 there will be an option to fix things like that.)

Also note that the function can be written in a simpler form (requires 2.3.23):

```
<#function min(a, b)>
  <#return (a < b)?then(a, b)>
</#function>
```

Answer (score 3):

Grumble. This works: I just don't know why... I used to get an error from Freemarker at the end of the function if I used `<#if>` rather than `<if>`.  Now it seems to work ok.

```
<#function min a b>
  <#if a gt b>
    <#return b />
  <#else>
    <#return a />
  </#if>
</#function>
```

Comment: This is why: `<if ...>` is just static text, and functions ignore static text (they don't output anything), so it has just returned at the first `#return`, which was run unconditionally since, again, `<if ...>` is just static text. (Non-whitespace static text should be an error, but that would be very backward-incompatible to fix now, after 10+ years... Maybe in 2.4.)

Comment: @ddekany -- add as an answer and I'll accept. (huh... 7 words in a row all starting with vowels)